# Mapping texture to square like the picture itself

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm orking since two weeks with opengl es and try to draw a image on a square.
The square is made of two triangles. When I draw the original image (http://satgeo.zum.de/satgeo/methoden/DHM_Web/Bilder/Grundidee/Raster.gif) it ends this way https://pl.vc/tfuc

That's my code:

```
public class Square {
    public static final String TAG = "Screen";
    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int STRIDE =
            (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT) * Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

    private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

             1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    private final VertexArray vertexArray;

    public Square(){
        vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
    }

    public void bindData(TextureShaderProgram textureShader){
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0, textureShader.getPositionAttributeLocation(),
                POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);

        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, textureShader.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(),
                TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    }

    public void draw(){
        int anzVertices = VERTEX_DATA.length / (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, anzVertices);
    }
}
```

How can I draw the texture without transformation and that it looks like the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you really don't need a vertex attribute for the texture coordinates. Since they are a direct mapping of the position, you can calculate the texture coordinates in the vertex shader, based on the value of the position attribute.

You will of course have to adjust for your naming, but the GLSL code in your vertex shader could look something like this:

```
attribute vec3 Position;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
...
    gl_Position = vec4(Position, 1.0);
    TexCoord = 0.5 * Position.xy + 0.5;
```

This maps the coordinates in the range [-1.0, 1.0] to texture coordinates in the range [0.0, 1.0].

This will save code, be more efficient, and less error prone.

If you do use texture coordinates, the ones you tried are clearly wrong. You can tell that they can't possibly be right by the fact that you're using the same texture coordinates for both triangles. So the same triangular part of the image would be mapped to both of the triangles you use to render the quad.

Not a functionality problem, but I would also recommend to use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`. This way, you will need only 4 vertices instead of 6. The vertex data (including texture coordinates, as long as you use them) would then look like this:

```
private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

and the draw call:

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, anzVertices);
```

Again, this will make your code simpler, more efficient, and with less redundancy you have fewer sources of errors.

Comment: Thanks. About the benifit of the performance: Are we already talking  about milliseconds?

Comment: The performance benefits are probably very minor, if measurable at all. I just don't like to be wasteful, especially if the more efficient solution is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your texture coordinates are wrong: For example, vertex[-1,-1,0] and [1,1,0] are connected by a diagonal of the square, so they should also have texture coordinates that lie on a diagonal. In your data, they have [0,0] and [1,0]. In addition, different vertex locations ([-1,1,0] and [1,-1,0]) with same texture coordinates (both [1,0]) will also not work out.

A corrected version could look like this:

```
-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
```

Just for completeness: The two triangles have different winding order, this will cause problems when backface culling is enabled.